# include users having no records

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database

In my relational Database and I have 2 tables:

**user**

> id | userName | email | col1 | col2

**log**

> ID |  user_id | cl1 | cl2 | cl3

And I want in my admin section to view all the users along with the count of their records.
I am using `SQLite3` as my DB

```
SELECT user_id,username,email,count(link)'count'
    FROM log,user
    where user_id=user.id group by user_id;
```

it works fine but doesn't include users having no record in log table please help how can I make it include all the *users* and show the `count` value as *0*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to include all the rows from `user` instead of old style of comma separated `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT user.id,username,email,count(link)'count' 
FROM user 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Log
ON Log.user_id=user.id 
group by user.id;
```